# epoch time converted has 5 hours ahead from emulator

Tags: dart, flutter

I did a simple function to convert an epoch time to a certain format

```
String convertEpochToHuman(int epoch) {
  final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(epoch * 1000);
  var format = new DateFormat('HH:mm, yyyy-MM-DD');
  return format.format(timeStamp);
}
```

Going to [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/), I got the "The current Unix epoch time is" value and put it in my code. When running it to the emulator, I got the right date, but the time is 5 hours ahead (I am in Canada East coast timezone). So, the result is the GMT value even if the emulator is eastern time.

How can I make sure the time conversion is done based on my timezone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `isUtc: true` (`false` by default)

```
final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(epoch * 1000, isUtc: true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Gunter, but I just discovered that my emulator was not set properly!!! That was code 18 issue! ;-) Thanks